# How to submit object to delete method in CXF REST?

Tags: java, rest, cxf

I have REST services with cxf.
My delete method cannot take a custom object:

```
    @DELETE
    @Path("/soemPath")
    @Produces({ "application/json", "application/xml" })
public void deleteStg(@PathParam("someId") String someId, CustomObject customObject) throws InvalidClientIdException, TermsOfUseBusinessException {
```

However, I cannot give the customObject (soapui does not have option for this one). If I change the method to update, everything works fine.
Can you please tell me how should I handle this to be able to transmit customObject as input param?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Usually" you don't send a payload body for a DELETE operation, perhaps this is the reason that it can not be defined in SoapUI. However, it is not forbidden as seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/299628/is-an-entity-body-allowed-for-an-http-delete-request).